# Pandas has trouble indexing by timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a program that sims data by the first day of the month, I'm running into an issue with indexing by date time. here's the code snippet:

```
  print(self.calendar_month.index[0])
  print(index)
  print(type(self.calendar_month.index[0]))
  print(type(index))
  data={
    #Position
    'verbose':False,
    'return_dict':True,
    'segment_center':np.array(self.calendar_month[index].tolist()).reshape((2,2)),

returns:
2022-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-01 00:00:00
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

KeyError: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I have a pandas dataframe indexed by date called calendar month.
I also have an index of a date, all as timestamps. The print statements show that it exists in calendar_month at the 0'th index, and they are the exact type and value, why do I get a key error?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

Consider a sample dataframe:

```
calendar_month = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':pd.date_range(datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 10)),
                                    'value': np.arange(1,11)})
calendar_month.set_index('date', inplace=True)
print(calendar_month)

            value
date             
2021-01-01      1
2021-01-02      2
2021-01-03      3
2021-01-04      4
2021-01-05      5
2021-01-06      6
2021-01-07      7
2021-01-08      8
2021-01-09      9
2021-01-10     10
```

Now let's check the index:

```
index = calendar_month.index[0]
print(index)
2021-01-01 00:00:00

print(type(calendar_month.index[0]))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Now when you try to do this:

```
calendar_month[index]
```

You are trying to access `2021-01-01 00:00:00` as a column which certainly does not exist in your dataframe and that's why it gives you this error: `KeyError: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00')`

What you need to do is this:

```
print(calendar_month.loc[index]) #Prints row with specified index as series.

value    1
Name: 2021-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: int32
```